# Google Drive stuck uploading files

Tags: samsung, google-drive

Three days ago I was uploading 6 files to a Google Drive shared folder. It's not the first time I do that, but surely this time was different because not only the files weren't uploaded but also since then I have this notification

[image]

To fix it, I tried to

1. Click cancel.
2. Restart the phone.
3. Force stop the app in settings.

yet none of these options worked.

Comment: Try clearing cache of Google drive app (enable show system apps in app list from settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve it, I've uninstalled the app and installed it back again. That solved the problem

[image]

Comment: No need to reinstall it, just clear data from app settings.